Is '"rel"="noopener noreferrer"' required if the internal link will be opened in new tab?
AFAIK the attributes target="_blank" and "rel"="noopener noreferrer" are required if the external link will be opened on new tab, but what about internal ones? Are they required the rel attribute for the security reasons?
I have created the diagram to organize the knowledge when we need to add target and rel attributes and with which values. Currently, the right branch is incomplete.


Who do you think requires them? They are not required ever.

It will be dependent upon your specific use case but you are likely correct in assuming that the rel="noopener noreferrer" is less urgent for internal links as I am assuming there is less risk of context and header information being an issue. You can read more about noopener and noreferrer here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/noopener
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/noreferrer
